# Working solution to check String for only integer numbers?

Tags: java, regex, string

I know this question was posted a lot and I checked some solutions but none were working perfectly for me.

What I want is to check whether a Stringinput in a TextField is valid or not. Valid entries are only positive integers, in other words everything that is >=0 and an integer.

I tried a solution something like this that I found:

```
try {
    int input = Integer.valueOf(fieldwaitAfterAction.getText());
    if(input < 0)) {
        validInput = false; 
    } else { 
        validInput = true; 
    }
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    validInput = false;
}
```

Works for most of the wrong patterns fine, but if I enter something like '+0' or '-0' it passes through which shouldn't be actually the case.
So I want a pure integer number without any characters at the beginning, in between or at the end.

What would the best solution be for this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @tim this one isn't working for me, don't know why.

met regex but don't know what the correct 'formula' would be to cover every character and pattern

Answer (score 2):

```
public static boolean checkForDigits(final String toCheck){
    boolean flag = true;
    char[] toCheckArray = toCheck.toCharArray();
    for(int index=0; index < toCheckArray.length, flag==true; index++){
        if( ! ( ( (int)toCheckArray[index] > 47 ) && ( (int)toCheckArray[index] < 58 ) ) ){
            flag = false;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

There you go. It returns true if all are digits, false if it does not.
It is O(n) time worst case. < O(n) if it detects anything other than a digit.

Comment: ey Charles... like you idea too.. but i should do this inside the loop `flag= ( ! ( ( (int)toCheckArray[index] > 47 ) && ( (int)toCheckArray[index] < 58 ) ) )`. Assign the boolean result directly to the variable ;), is more direct, don't you think so?

Comment: Almost right, except make a special case for the first character to check if it is 0.  If it is, and the string contains anything else, this is invalid.

Comment: Victor, it is not. I don't want to waste time assigning a value when it's not needed. I honestly should have just put return false instead of using a flag at all. Orch, he never specified that case. All integers are valid and 024 is still an integer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to put = to.If i understood your question correctly this should fix your problem:

```
try{
                String input_string=fieldwaitAfterAction.getText()

                int input = Integer.valueOf(input_string);
                if(input <= 0)){
                    validInput = false; 

                }
                else{ validInput = true; }
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException e){
                    validInput = false;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address his issue with + or -

Comment: @orch if we enter +9 +0 as input string it works fine.Can you help me understand the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Regex `^\d+$` to check if a input contains only positive number.

```
^ assert position at start of the string
\d+ match a digit [0-9]
    Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
$ assert position at end of the string
```

In Java code:

```
String[] arr = { "-123", "123a", "0", "123" };
String regex = "^\\d+$";
for (String str : arr) {
  Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str);
  if (matcher.find())
    System.out.println("String " + str + " is a positive number.");
  else 
    System.out.println("String " + str + " is NOT a positive  number.");
}
```

prints

```
String -123 is NOT a positive number.
String 123a is NOT a positive number.
String 0 is a positive number.
String 123 is a positive number.
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this always do the magic....

```
  try {
    Integer.parseInt(theStringToEval);
    // is this line is reach.. it is a int
  }
  catch (NumberFormatException e){
    // is the flow goes here
  }
```

But it allows integer with signs... You could create a method for your convenience that hide this implementation details and add the check for the signs in there...

```
  public static boolean isPlainInteger (String string) {
    if (string.startsWith("-") || string.startsWith("+")) {
      return false;
    }

    try {
      Integer.parseInt(string);
      return true;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e){
      return false;
    }
  }
```

And you can achieve it through regex too.... perhaps this one could help.

```
 private static Pattern plainIntegerPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
 public static boolean isPlainInteger (String string) {
    return plainIntegerPattern.matcher(string).matches();
 }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.ValueOf` allows `+` ans `-` signs. As per javadoc

> ...The characters in the string must all be digits of the specified radix (as determined by whether java.lang.Character.digit(char, int) returns a nonnegative value), except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' to indicate a positive value

So Your code will break for any value having `+` followed by an integer and also `+0` and `-0` as both of them will result as `0`. I'll give solution using regex.

```
String str = fieldwaitAfterAction.getText();
if (str == null) {
    retrun false;
}
String regex = "^(\\d+)$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    int val = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(0));
    if (val > 0) {
        return true;
    }
}
retrun false;
```

This way you could handle situation like `088` not being a valid input to you by using reges `^[^0](\\d+)$`.

Answer (score 0):

Checks if the given input is a integer number, not a valid Java Integer (Integer.MAX_VALUE).

```
validInput = fieldwaitAfterAction.getText().length > 0
                &&  fieldwaitAfterAction.getText().matches("[0-9]+");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regexp, like   "(^0|[1-9]*\d)$". This allows you to put 0 or any positive integer.

```
fieldwaitAfterAction.getText().matches("(^0|[1-9]*\\d)$")
```

Remember that using regexp like \d+ won't work, because it will accept strings like "001243"